# How did the FAA decide that firewalls should resist fire for 15 minutes specifically?

Tags: aircraft-design, faa-regulations, fire

I'm searching for information on where the criteria of 15 minutes come from, in which the firewall is subjected to by a flame of 2000 °F (according to the now-obsolete [14 CFR 23.1191](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=2d66d951c4764c009c4fe30f63e5feb9&pitd=20150101&node=se14.1.23_11191&rgn=div8)).

I know that this time includes mainly a reaction time. This reaction time is the time from the appearance of a fire in a compartment to the fire being recognized by the pilot.

Can anybody provide more information about the 15 minutes?

Comment: Most likely a time considered to take from the start of the fire, noticing it, shutting off fuel, and burning off the fuel already delivered to engine, plus added safety margin of some minutes (30% maybe).

Comment: I suspect that this criteria is part of the rules which are not "computed" but rather decided based on experience and various non-analytical considerations.

Comment: You might be able to dig it out of the federal register. It might also be a carryover from the CAB rules that precede the regulations in CFR Title 14.

Comment: It's possibly carried over from railroad requirements.  One of the weirdest things I've learned in studying the 7110 is that our time/distance rules  (10 minutes/20 miles) came out of railroad timetable requirements that were initially set forth in the 1800s.